# Creating/extracting RAR files on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, compression, archiving, rar

I would like to be able to create RAR files easily on Snow Leopard with some sort of GUI utility.  I know that RARlabs maintains a Mac version of the RAR command line utility, but I don't want to have to open Terminal to manage simple archives.  I also need the capability to password-protect the RAR file during archive.

Is there a tool out there that can do these things?  Doesn't necessarily have to be free, but that would be a plus, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

The Unarchiver is most commonly used and it is free.

http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html

You can also go for a classic program called Stuffit (http://www.stuffit.com/mac-expander-download.html)

Comment: Can it *create* RAR files?

Answer (score 1):

While The Unarchiver is good, some RAR formats will cause it to choke. For all my RAR files I use [RAR Expander](http://rarexpander.sourceforge.net/). It's free, fast, and handles all the RAR files I've come across without any issues freezing up or taking a bad password, pretending to expand it for ten minutes, and then failing.

The Unarchiver can't be beat with ZIP, Gzip, Bzip2, and other archive formats, but RAR is something it doesn't do as splendidly.

Comment: RAR Expander's AppleScript for expanding all RARs in subfolders was quite handy.